# Selenium Actions(Driver).Click(Elem) removes Elem from the DOM?

Tags: c#, dom, selenium

Running into a very strange issue running a selenium automation test.

We have a home-grown wrapper around the selenium objects, but I've extracted all of the Selenium objects from the wrappers and run directly using the pure Selenium API and replicated the issue there.

Basically what's happening is when the "Click" method is called on an action for a specific hyperlink on my site, the hyperlink just disappears (not hidden, it is completely removed from the DOM).  This does not happen when operating the site manually.

```
var elem = //element as located by xpath;
new Actions(driver).Click(elem).Build().Perform();
//Actions = OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions
```

Relevant DOM before the above code executes:

```
<div ng-show="Event">
    <a data-xpath="customXpathUsedToLocateElement">
        <i class="eventIcon"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

Relevant DOM after the above code executes:

```
<div ng-show="Event">

</div>
```

Has anybody ever seen this issue and know how to fix it?

---

***Edit***

This issue appears to be limited to tests that run in FireFox

Comment: Does this still happen when you call the click method directly on the element rather than via an action builder?

Comment: Yes it does.  I've tried several different ways to do the clicking, all have the same effect

Comment: What if you send the click event to the icon?

Comment: Nope.  I hadn't tried that so it was a good idea, but no change in the behavior

Comment: Correction: On closer examination, the <i> tag disappeared, but the <a> tag was still present after making that change

Comment: I have been doing selenium for several years and can safely say that I have never heard of a similar issue

Comment: Thanks for investigating anyway. I knew it was odd when Google didn't have an answer already :-)